# justify-end not working properly on vue component buttons

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

In my vuejs component, I have a form with submit button and a cancel button.

I want my buttons to align right

Following is my current code

```
 <template slot="modal_actions">
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-end">
                        <close-overlay class="h-full" identifier="addNewScheduleModal">
                            <cs-button variant="blank">Cancel</cs-button>
                        </close-overlay>
                        <disables-submit-on-errors
                            :identifier="identifier"
                            @proceed="addNewSchedule"
                        >
                        <loading-button ref="submitBtnSave" size="normal">
                            Save & Close
                        </loading-button>
                        </disables-submit-on-errors>
                    </div>
                </template>
```

Even though I'm using `justify-end` class, still the button are aligned left...

I'm struggling to find what I'm doing wrong and align them right....

I'm using tailwind-css

Comment: can you try `justify-content: flex-end;` ?

Comment: is your loading button is  right of cancel button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `cancel` button is at left and `loading` button is at right of cancel button.

Then there are two ways,

1. you can change the order of buttons inside `div` like this:

```
 <template slot="modal_actions">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-end">
         <loading-button ref="submitBtnSave" size="normal">
             Save & Close 
         </loading-button>
         <disables-submit-on-errors
             :identifier="identifier"
             @proceed="addNewSchedule"
         >
         <close-overlay class="h-full" identifier="addNewScheduleModal">
               <cs-button variant="blank">Cancel</cs-button>
         </close-overlay>
                 .
                 .
   </div>
</template>
```

2. You can change the flex-direction to `row-reverse` by adding class `flex-row-reverse` to the div. I have created a similar example below for understanding purpose.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="space-y-4">
<h3>Before</h3>
<div class="flex items-center justify-end h-96 w-full bg-red-200 space-x-10">
  <div class="h-56 w-1/3 bg-red-700">Cancel Button</div>
  <div class="h-56 w-1/3 bg-green-700">Loading Button</div>
</div>
<h3>After</h3>
<div class="flex flex-row-reverse items-center justify-end h-96 w-full bg-red-200 space-x-10">
  <div class="h-56 w-1/3 bg-red-700">Cancel Button</div>
  <div class="h-56 w-1/3 bg-green-700">Loading Button</div>
</div>
</div>
```